# Change of the keyboard language and operating system language on users' computers using GPO (Windows Server)

Tags: windows, active-directory, group-policy

I am responsible for managing a fleet of computers in my organization, and I would like to know how to configure the change of keyboard language and operating system language on users' computers using Group Policy Objects (GPO) in a Windows environment.

Could someone please help me understand the steps and best practices for this process? Are there any specific recommendations or pitfalls I should be aware of?

Could someone please help me understand the steps and best practices for this process? Are there any specific recommendations or pitfalls I should be aware of?

Thank you very much for any guidance and advice on this task.

I've tried searching online for a solution, but it hasn't been helpful, and I can't seem to find a straightforward GPO for language changes. I already have the additional ADMX files downloaded.

I also came across information suggesting that I need to install an additional language pack, but it wasn't explained how this would help, and I couldn't find any information on it either.

I've read that PowerShell scripts may be an option, but I don't have much information on how to proceed with that.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to brute force something quick, you could run `Set-WinSystemLocale xx-yy` in a system startup/shutdown script.

Ideally you would have config mgmt report on devices that are non compliant and run scripts against them.

Ideally the system locale should match the operating system. Changing it to a different value should be tested.

You may find DISM more useful to manage the selection, from a startup script.

`DISM /Set-UILang:<language_name>`

`DISM /Set-SysLocale:<locale_name>`

`DISM /Set-UserLocale:<locale_name>`

`DISM /Set-InputLocale:<input_locale>:<keyboard_layout>`

`DISM Set-AllIntl:<language_name>`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-international-settings-in-windows?view=windows-11

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/international/set-winsystemlocale?view=windowsserver2022-ps

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-languages-and-international-servicing-command-line-options?view=windows-11

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-languages-and-international-servicing-command-line-options?view=windows-11#set-uilang

Comment: hey, thanks for your reply. I will check this solution as soon as I can and give an answer :)